# Python Socket Doesn't Work Between Host and VM

Tags: python, sockets

I am learning python socket programming. Everything works fine if I run locally (both server and client scripts). However, when I moved the server script to a VM (Ubuntu 14.04) and run the client script from the host os (Windows 7) I got this error:

```
 ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the
 target machine actively refused it
```

When I tried running the client inside the VM, it works just fine (except if I use the IP address i.e:192.168.1.6, I have to use it in both scripts). From my search, I found that linux does not activate the firewall by default. What did I do wrong?

Both machines can see each other ( i have set Samba between them, can ping others etc). This is really confusing for me.

Comment: Are you binding to `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: I am binding to the VM Ip address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this may solve the problem.

You have a `bind` call in your server code, it looks like `sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 3333))`, where 3333 is the server port number. Change the IP address to the empty string, or `'0.0.0.0'`, so it would look like `sock.bind(('', 3333))`. Then start the client again.

The original `bind` call binds the server socket only to the loopback interface (`lo`), which works only within the VM. By binding to the wildcard address (`''` or `'0.0.0.0'`) the server will accept connections from any IP address.

Comment: i tried binding the server to 0.0.0.0 but still the same error on client running in the host machine. however, client running in the same Vm has no problem.

Comment: OK that fix the problem. apparently I forgot to update the `connect` address too.